# Gson parse two different APIs results with one meaning

Tags: java, android, json, api, gson

My application works with 2 different APIs - Last.fm and VK.com, and despite of pretty similar classes like User with name, image and so on. Problem is that Last.fm returns image as array by quality

```
image:[
    {
    #text: "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/...",
    size: "small"
    },
    {
    #text: "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/...",
    size: "medium"
    },
    {
    #text: "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/...",
    size: "large"
    },
    {
    #text: "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/...",
    size: "extralarge"
    }
    ]
```

And VK returns only one url for image

```
"photo":"http:\/\/cs537.vkontakte.ru\/..."
```

Is there any handsome way to deal with this situation with on model class Image in my application using Gson? Or should I separate different APIs entirely in application? What is the best tactics?

And one mini question - is there any way to get just one "String url" element from Last.fm images array via Gson?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Getting the feeling that you can get it done by Gson(by making global class which contains all possible objects).

Answer (score 0):

You can write custom [deserializer](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization). An in vk request use vkdeserializer, in last.fm lstfmdeserializer.